# Напишите самое простое решение задачи 'Объединить два массива чередуя их элементы'

Tags: javascript, массивы, соревнование

Как-то давно наткнулся в нете, на одну из задач которую возможно задать при собеседовании на место *«Front-End Web Developer»*. Так вот ее условие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю объединяющиеся массивы могут быть разной длины, поэтому нужно написать **универсальную** функцию, которая сможет вернуть результат двух массивов разной длинны.

```js
let num = [1,2,3,4];

let str = ['a','b','c'];

function sum(a,b) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(b.length, a.length); i++){
   result = result.concat(a[i]).concat(b[i])
  }

 console.log(result)
 return result;
} 

sum(num, str);
```

У меня получилось что у второго объединяющегося массива последний элемент может быть 'undefined'.

Как можно было бы решить по другому и интересней?

**Правильный ответ получит тот у кого решение будет самым коротким и без 'undefined' как у меня.**
<del>Чтобы увидеть самый 'простой' ответ, вопрос будет закрыт в 15:00
пятница, 6 апреля 2018 г. (GMT+1).</del>Так как ответы увеличиваются с каждым днем, вопрос закроется в 15:00 понедельник, 9 апреля 2018 г. (GMT+1).

Comment: *голос получит тот у кого* А конкурс объявить - не? *функцию, которая сможет вернуть два массива разной длинны* Может, всё же ПРИНЯТЬ два массива разной длины и вернуть ОДИН?

Comment: 6 апреля это пятница (: сегодня четверг 5 апреля

Comment: @teran , теперь точно в пятницу закроется :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

вариант решения

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];
let b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

let s = Math.max(a.length, b.length)*2;
let d =  [a,b];
let r = [];

for(i=0;i<s;i++){
    let v =  d[i%2][Math.floor(i/2)];
    if(v != undefined) r.push(v);    
}

console.log(r)
```

вторая ревизия, укоротил код заменой `for` на `while`, и `math.floor` на формулу

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];
let b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

let s = Math.max(a.length, b.length)*2,
    d = [a,b],
    r = [],
    v, i=-1; 


while(s-i++){
    v =  d[i%2][(i-i%2)/2];        // или d[i%2][~~(i/2)]
    if(v != undefined) r.push(v);    
}
console.log(r)
```

по заявкам, для произвольного числа массивов.

```js
const merge = (...d) => {
   let c = d.length, i = -1, v, r = [],
       s = Math.max(...d.map(x => x.length))*c;
       
   while(s-i++){
       (v = d[i%c][~~(i/c)]) != undefined ? r.push(v):0;           
   }
   return r;
};

console.log(
    merge(['a','b'], [1,2,3], ['а','б','в','г'])
)
```

Comment: что за демон O.o . отличный ответ

Comment: ещё бы добить под любое количество массивов

Comment: `Math.floor(x)` можно укоротить до `~~x`

Comment: @Zergatul точно! жаль выигрыш всего  2 символа

Comment: @qwabra вот вам с произвольным числом

Comment: @teran, тю. и снова не успел :  )

Comment: @qwabra что не успел?

Comment: @teran, :) да всё не успел. начиная с вашего первого ответа. первый раз - (аналогичная мысль витала + универсальная для любого количества) ;  второй - (думал над пустыми тактами можно ли и нужно ли от них избавляться)

Comment: Можно сократить на 2 символа заменив `[~~(i/c)]` на `[i/c|0]`

Answer (score 11):

```js
let one = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let two = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function arrayConcat(a, b) {
  let result = [];
  let len = a.length >= b.length ? a.length : b.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i])
      result.push(a[i]);
    if (b[i])
      result.push(b[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(arrayConcat(one, two));
```

Comment: как то слишком тривиально для задачки на собеседовании и для минимальной длины. решение в лоб.

Comment: @teran зато все понятно)

Comment: @teran, ©Напишите самое простое решение задачи

Comment: @qwabra если под самым простым понимается самое понятное, то мы его тут и обсуждаем. Если самое короткое, то видимо оно будет другим

Answer (score 9):

```js
let num = [1,2,3,4];
let str = ['a','b','c'];

const sum = (ar1, ar2) => (ar1.length > ar2.length ? ar1 : ar2)
  .reduce((res, el, i) => ((ar2[i] && res.concat(ar2[i])) || res).concat(el), []);

console.log(sum(num,str));

/* Оба ответа (мой и @Sergey Glazirin) грешат одним
- если в исходных массивах будут значения типа `null`, `0`, `undefined`
- они будут съедены. */
console.log(sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], [null, undefined, 0, '', false]));


// Так что стоит добавить проверку на undefined:
const better_sum = (ar1, ar2) => (ar1.length > ar2.length ? ar1 : ar2)
  .reduce((res, el, i) => ((typeof ar2[i] !== 'undefined' && res.concat(ar2[i])) || res).concat(el), []);

 console.log(better_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], [null, undefined, 0, '', false]));
```

Comment: хорошее замечание про `undedined` учту на будущее. Задача переходит из разряда легких задач, с коротким решением)

Answer (score 8):

Ну хотите короткое - вот креатив от меня:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function merge(a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; a.length;)
    b.splice(i++ * 2, 0, a.shift());
  return b;
}

console.log(merge(a, b));
```

Вроде достаточно коротко, однако модифицирует исходные массивы))0)

Comment: плюсанул, самое короткое и понятное пока что будет. правда особо не расширить на большее число массивов

Comment: @teran ну изначально задачи расширения и не стояло) Я вот думаю, может как-то можно сократить саму запись цикла...

Comment: `i+=2` написать и выиграть 1 символ :D

Comment: `while(b.length)` написать

Comment: @teran мне не нравится инкремент с присвоением, очень некрасивый оператор) а `b.length` - придется переносить `i`. Я кажется придумал, секундочку

Comment: @teran вот, так короче) `b[0]` вместо `b.length`

Comment: так на `b = [1,2,0]` не сработает. да и в целом, если в массиве встретится `0,null`

Comment: @teran да, точняк, забыл, что в `js` приводится это все дело... Но все равно, если перенести инкремент из шапки цикла, то можно сократить на 1 символ)

Answer (score 7):

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let str = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function merge(a1, a2) {
    let result = [];
    while (a1.length || a2.length)
    {
        result.push(a1.shift());
        result.push(a2.shift());
    }
    return result.filter(i => i !== undefined);
}

console.log(merge(num, str))
```

Answer (score 5):

Вряд ли рекурсию можно считать очень понятным вариантом, но зато как коротко...

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function merge(a, b)
{
    return (a.length > 0) ? [a[0]].concat(merge(b, a.slice(1))) : b;
}

console.log(merge(a, b));
```

Comment: тогда уж `let merge = (a, b)=>(a.length > 0) ? [a[0]].concat(merge(b, a.slice(1))) : b;`

Comment: @qwabra, спасибо! очень слабо знаю JavaScript, и не думал, что скомпилится лямбда, вызывающая себя рекурсивно из переменной, в которую она присваивается. проверить, когда постил, к сожалению, поленился :) помню, что Java 8 вроде не позволяет такого

Answer (score 4):

Модифицированный вариант от @Zergatul

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let str = ['a', 'b', 'c', undefined, null];

function merge(a1, a2) {
    let x, y, result = [];
    do {
      if (x = a1.length) {
        result.push(a1.shift());
      }
      if (y = a2.length) {
        result.push(a2.shift());
      }
    } while (x > 1 || y > 1);

    return result;
}
console.log(merge(num, str));
```

Другой вариант

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let str = ['a', 'b', 'c', undefined, null, false];

function merge(a1, a2) {
  return a1.reduce(function(result, current) {
    result.push(current);
    if (a2.length) {
      result.push(a2.shift());
    }
    return result;
  }, []).concat(a2);
}
console.log(merge(num, str));
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример с использованием [генераторов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A)

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let str = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function* sum(a, b) {
  var [min, max] = a.length < b.length ? [a, b] : [b, a];
  for (var i = 0; i < min.length; i++) {
    yield a[i];
    yield b[i];
  }
  yield* max.slice(i);
}

console.log([...sum(num, str)])
```

И без

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let str = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function sum(a, b) {
  var [min, max, res] = a.length < b.length ? [a, b, []] : [b, a, []];
  for (var i = 0; i < min.length; i++) {
    res.push(...[a[i], b[i]]);
  }
  return [...res, ...max.slice(i)];
}

console.log(sum(num, str));
```

Answer (score 4):

1. это задачка на простую работу с матрицой - перевод матрицы в массив
2. почему-то все отвечающие забыть про интересный элемент массива `empty`
   по этому поводу я даже решил создать вопрос/ответ
   [Есть ли бóльшая пустота чем undefined?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/810426/)

### убрать empty оставить undefined

```js
void function () {

    let num = Array.from(Array(10),(_k,_i) => _i) // [0..9]
    let str = ['a','b','c'];
    let c = [undefined,null,false]

    /**
     * @param {any[][]} _m матрица (двумерный массив)
     */
    function merge(..._m) {
        let res = Array(sum(_m.map(_k => _k.length)))
        // --
        for (var _i = 0; _i < _m.length; _i++) {
            for (var _j = 0; _j < _m[_i].length; _j++) {
                let _val = _m[_i][_j]
                somethingDo((_j * _m.length + _i),_val)
            }
        }
        // --
        function somethingDo(_i,_val) {
            res[_i] = _val
        }
        // --
        return res
    }
    // --
    let res = merge(num,str,c)
    log(() => '<br>')

    log(() => toArrOfString(res))

    log(() => '<br>')

    let n = res.filter((_k,_i) => (_i in res))  // убрать empty оставить undefined
    log(() => toArrOfString(n))

    log(() => '<br>')
    log(() => [res.length,(num.length + str.length + c.length),n.length])

    // ----------
    function toArrOfString(_arr) {
        let res = []
        let val = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < _arr.length; i++) {
            val = _arr[i]
            // проверка на `empty`
            // эквивалентно if (Object.keys(_arr).indexOf(''+i) !== -1) {
            if (i in _arr) {
                // проверка на `undefined`
                if (val === undefined) {
                    res.push('undefined')
                } else {
                    // res.push(String(val))
                    res.push('' + val)
                }
            } else {
                res.push('empty')
            }
        }
        //---
        return res
    }
    function sum(_arr) {
        let r = 0;
        _arr.forEach(_k => { r += _k });
        return r
    }
}()
```

```html
<script>function log(...args){let d=document,c='createElement',ach='appendChild',i='innerHTML';let p=d[c]('p');p.style.borderBottom='dashed 1px';p.style.borderLeft='solid 2px #49b3bf';if(args&&args[0]&&args[0] instanceof Function){let str=args[0].toString();if(`() => '<br>'`!==str){let strArr=str.split('\n');let h=strArr.length;let w=Math.max(0,...strArr.map(_str=>_str.length||0));let t=d[c]('textarea');t[i]=str;t.rows=''+h;t.style.width=w+'ch';p[ach](t);};let p2=d[c]('p');p2[i]=args[0]();p[ach](p2);}else{for(let _var of args){let p1=d[c]('p');p1[i]=_var;p[ach](p1);};};d.body[ach](p);};</script>
<style>p {margin: 0;margin-top: 10px;padding: 0;padding-bottom: 7px;padding-left: 7px;}</style>
```

в приведённом мной примере показан трюк с `empty` элементами, то есть матрица переводится в массив содержащий эти самые элементы вместо `undefined` (arr1 = res), которые потом убираются(arr2 = n)

```
let arr1 = [0, a, undefined, 1, b, null, 2, c, false, 3, , , 4, , , 5, , , 6, , , 7, , , 8, , , 9]
let arr2 = [0, a, undefined, 1, b, null, 2, c, false, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

ещё одни момент:
arr1 имеет преимущество перед arr2 - его можно обратно преобразовать в матрицу, при этом с его элементами можно работать так же, как с элементами массива arr2 но с учётом некоторых нюансов - читай по ссылке в начале ответа

Answer (score 3):

## Кажется, один из самых коротких вариантов :)

### Обновлённый вариант для современных браузеров:

```js
function merge(a, b) {
  return [...a.flatMap((x, i) => i in b ? [x, b[i]] : [x]), ...b.slice(a.length)]
}

console.log(merge([1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c']))
console.log(merge([1], ['a','b','c']))
console.log(merge([1,2,3,4], ['a']))
console.log(merge([], ['a','b','c']))
console.log(merge([1,2,3,4], []))
console.log(merge([1,undefined,3,4], ['a','b',undefined]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

### Оригинальный ответ:

```js
function merge(a, b) {
  return [].concat(...a.map((x, i) => i in b ? [x, b[i]] : [x]), b.slice(a.length))
}

console.log(merge([1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c']))
console.log(merge([1], ['a','b','c']))
console.log(merge([1,2,3,4], ['a']))
console.log(merge([], ['a','b','c']))
console.log(merge([1,2,3,4], []))
console.log(merge([1,undefined,3,4], ['a','b',undefined]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```