# Есть ли бóльшая пустота чем undefined?

Tags: javascript, массивы

`#delete` `#undefined` `#array` `#empty`

Да, есть.

Думаю, всем известно, что для удаления элемента, в JS, используется `undefined`:

```
lеt variable = 'string'
variable = undefined
```

Им не часто пользуются, ведь в JS работает автоматический сборщик мусора, и мало кто заботится об удалении элементов. Ещё реже встречаются люди, которые знают о существовании метода `delete`, а тем более те, кто замечал различия в использовании `undefined` и `delete`.

```
let o = {
    A: 9,
    B: 9,
}
delete o['A']
console.log(
    Object.keys(o)//массив//["B"]//length: 1
);
```

Далее в моём вопросе, **и следующем за ним ответе**, будет рассмотрен частный, но очень важный, случай различия в использовании `undefined` и `delete` в контексте массивов.

### Итак (барабанная дробь) внимание, вопрос…

В чём различия при удалении **элемента массива** методами(подход, способ) `undefined` и `delete` и какие серьёзные и не очень последствия за этим следуют?

```
let arr = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
delete arr[0]
arr[1] = undefined
arr[2] = void 0
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14967535/2076787

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75630/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwabra).

Comment: delete высвобождает память, а `= undefined` не высвобождает её поэтому другая программа свои данные туда поместить не может

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В: В чём различия при удалении элемента массива методами undefined и delete ?
О: оператор `delete` удаляет пару «ключ-значение».

В: Какие серьёзные и не очень последствия за этим следуют?
О: так как на месте удалённого элемента с помощью `delete` остаётся `empty` (дырка) - весь второй раздел будет посвящён сравнению поведения

операторов:

- for
- for in
- for of

и некоторых методов:

- Array.forEach
- Array.map
- Array.filter
- Object.keys
- Object.values

при работе с массивами, содержащими `empty` или `undefined`.

Сразу хочу сделать заявление:

Здесь будут рассмотрены только массивы `Array`!

Здесь **не будут** рассматриваться типизированные массивы вроде: `Int16Array`; и всякие: `Set`, `NodeList`, `ArrayBuffer` (да-да, кое что из этого списка не массив).

И ещё, небольшое замечание: иной раз не помешает убедиться что вы работаете с массивом (если собираетесь его модифицировать) а не с `[Symbol.iterator]: function*`, например.

---

### структура:

1. немного теории

   1. как оно выглядит в консоле **chrome** , **filefox** и **stackoverflow**
   2. последняя запятая игнорируется
   3. функции, используемые мной здесь
   4. для тех, кто не хочет использовать `empty` и вообще не хочет читать многабукаф ибо
   5. где ещё почитать
   6. ищу информацию
2. много практики

   1. для иллюстрации "проблемы"
   2. count
   3. замеры времени
   4. персонально для @yar85
   5. оператор расширения (spread)

## 1. немного теории

> [https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#удаление-из-массива](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)
>
> оператор `delete` удаляет пару «ключ-значение».

да, и в этом месте, в массиве, образуется "дырка" (`empty`), если попробовать прочитать значение из этой "дырки", то оно будет `undefined`

> Это – все, что он делает.

на самом деле, оператор `delete` сразу освобождает память, а ещё возвращает `true/false` но в контексте элементов массива нас это не интересует, т.к. он всегда будет возвращать `true` (даже в случае с `empty` и `undefined`)

> Обычно же при удалении из массива мы хотим, чтобы оставшиеся элементы сдвинулись и заполнили образовавшийся промежуток.
>
> Поэтому для удаления используются специальные методы: из начала – `shift`, с конца – `pop`, а из середины – `splice`

с `shift` и `pop` всё как всегда.
а вот при работе со `splice` есть небольшой нюанс и, на самом деле, связан он с оператором расширения ( `...` `spread` ) - с помощью `splice` **не получится вставить** `empty` элемент/ы, а `spread` превращает `empty` в `undefined`.

### 1.1 как оно выглядит в консоле **chrome** , **filefox** и **stackoverflow**

````
```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
delete arr[1]
delete arr[2]
arr[3] = undefined
arr[4] = undefined
console.log(arr)
// эквивалентно
// console.log([0,,,undefined,undefined,5])
```
````

в консоле **chrome** :

```
[ 0,    empty × 2    , undefined, undefined, 5 ]
```

в консоле **filefox** :

```
[ 0, <2 empty slots> , undefined, undefined, 5 ]
```

в консоле **stackoverflow** :

```
[ 0, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 5 ]
```

как вывести в **stackoverflow** :

````
```js
log(() => // "[ 0, empty, empty, undefined, undefined, 1 ]"
    arrToString([0,,,undefined,undefined,1,])) // <- запятая в конце
```
````

### 1.2 последняя запятая игнорируется

относительно недавно появилась возможность писать в конце запятую, которая **игнорируется** (что при создании объектов, что при создании массивов)

````
```js
let a = ['A','B']
let b = ['A','B',] // <- запятая в конце
log(() => Object.keys(a)) // ["0", "1"]
log(() => Object.keys(b)) // ["0", "1"]
log(() => a.length) // 2
log(() => b.length) // 2
```
````

### 1.3 функции, используемые мной здесь

```js
let group = _f => {
    console.group(_f.name || ((_f.prototype) ? _f : 'anonym'))
    try { _f() } catch (_e) { console.log(_e.stack) }
    console.groupEnd()
}
let log = (_f) => _f instanceof Function
    ? console.log(_f,_f())
    : console.log(_f)

group(() => {
    let hw = () => 'Hello World'
    // -->                                       // вывод в консоле хрома
    log(hw)                                      // () => 'Hello World' "Hello World"
    log(() => 'Hello World 2')                   // () => 'Hello World 2' "Hello World 2"
    //  <--
})
group(() => {
    // -->                                              // я же буду писать в комментариях только правую часть
    log(() => arrToString(['hello','world']))           // "[ hello, world ]"
    log(() => arrToString([1,,,undefined,undefined,2])) // "[ 1, empty, empty, undefined, undefined, 2 ]"
    // -----------
    // ОСТОРОЖНО !
    // -----------
    //                                                          // вывод в консоле хрома
    log(() => arrToString([1,[11,,22],,undefined,undefined,2])) // "[ 1, 11,,22, empty, undefined, undefined, 2 ]"
    //  <--
})
group(() => {
    throw new Error('qwa')
})
function arrToString(_arr) {
    if (Object.prototype.arrToString.call(_arr) !== "[object Array]") throw new TypeError('_arr !==  "[object Array]"')
    let res = []
    let val = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < _arr.length; i++) {
        val = _arr[i]
        // проверка на `empty`
        // эквивалентно if (Object.keys(_arr).indexOf(''+i) !== -1) {
        if (i in _arr) {
            // проверка на `undefined`
            if (val === undefined) {
                res.push('undefined')
            } else {
                // res.push(String(val))
                res.push('' + val)
            }
        } else {
            res.push('empty')
        }
    }
    //---
    return `[ ${res.join(', ')} ]`
}
```

### 1.4. для тех, кто не хочет использовать `empty` и вообще не хочет читать многабукаф ибо

1. неожиданная встрече с `empty` в чужом коде может вызвать головную боль
   ; ) поэтому делаем заметку в голове и кликаем по звёздочке вверху
2. пример создания массива заданной длинны с помощью конструктора `Array` :

   ````
   ```js
   let arr1 = Array(5) // == [,,,,,]
   log(() => arr1) // [empty × 5]

   let arr2 = Array.from({
   length: 5
   },(_key,_index) => undefined)
   log(() => arr2) // [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
   ```
   ````
3. для перебора используйте только `for (var _i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {let val = arr[i] }`, ну почти, и да, я серьёзно!! посмотрите раздел `2.2`

### 1.5 где ещё почитать

унарные операторы, в частности `delete`

- [mozilla.org Унарные_операторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)
- [mozilla.org delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
- [(eng) Глубокий анализ оператора delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

удаление из массива

- [javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

оператор `spread`

- [javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-spread)
- [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

управление памятью

- [learn.javascript.ru/memory-management](https://learn.javascript.ru/memory-management)

### 1.6 ищу информацию

#### CanIUse

1. final trailing comma - последняя разделительная запятая ( игнорируется )
2. empty элементы (по моему с IE11)

## 2. много практики

1. мой ответ и так содержит более 500 строк (кто не верит - нажмите править и посмотрите)
   поэтому этот раздел будет иметь вид:

   log(()=> функция) // результат в консоле
2. он не охватывает все возможные методы и ситуации, а лишь демонстрирует ключевые моменты

### 2.1 для иллюстрации "проблемы"

#### JQuery

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```js
let arr = [,,,]
let count = null

console.log(`arr.length: ${arr.length}`)

{
  console.log('$.each')
  count = 0
  $.each(arr,_k=>{
    count++
  })
  console.log(`count: ${count}`) // count: 3
}

{
  console.log('arr.forEach')
  count = 0
  arr.forEach(_k=>{
    count++
  })
  console.log(`count: ${count}`) // count: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### underscorejs

> http://underscorejs.ru/
>
> Кроме того, Underscore умеет делегировать вызовы, т.е. если код выполняется в современном браузере, который имеет нативные реализации таких методов, как: forEach, map, reduce, filter, every, some и indexOf, то будут вызваны именно они.

#### ничего не предвещало проблемы - простая функция сложения

дана функция

```
let sum = (arrOfNumbers) => {
    let res = 0
    arrOfNumbers.forEach(_number => { res += _number })
    return res
}
```

и массив

```
let arr = [ 10, 3, 5 ]
```

проверка с применением `delete arr[1]`

```
() => sum(arr) 15
```

проверка с применением `arr[1] = undefined`

```
() => sum(arr) NaN
```

исходники:

```js
// /*
group(function sum() {

let sum = (arrOfNumbers) => {
    let res = 0
    arrOfNumbers.forEach(_number => { res += _number })
    return res
}
let a = 10,b = 3,c = 5,Arr = () => [a,b,c]

group(function testDelete() {
    let arr = Arr(); log(() => arrToString(arr)) // "[ 10, 3, 5 ]"
    delete arr[1]
    log(() => sum(arr)) // 15
})

group(function testUndefined() {
    let arr = Arr(); log(() => arrToString(arr)) // "[ 10, 3, 5 ]"
    arr[1] = undefined
    log(() => sum(arr)) // NaN
})

})
// */
```

```html
<script>let group=a=>{let b=console;b.group(a.name||((a.prototype)?a:'anonym'));try { a() } catch (d) { b.log(d) }b.groupEnd()};let log = a => a instanceof Function ? console.log(a,a()) : console.log(a); function arrToString(a) { if ('[object Array]' !== Object.prototype.toString.call(a)) throw new TypeError('_arr !==  "[object Array]"'); let b = [],c = null; for (var d = 0; d < a.length; d++)c = a[d],d in a ? void 0 === c ? b.push('undefined') : b.push('' + c) : b.push('empty'); return `[ ${b.join(', ')} ]` }</script>
```

### 2.2 count

дано два массива

```
let a = [,,,'k3']
let b = [undefined,undefined,undefined,'k3']
```

суть теста - перебрать элементы массива и посчитать "тики"

результат:

```
count
    () => Object.keys(a)       ["3"]
    () => Object.values(a)     ["k3"]
    () => Object.keys(b)   (4) ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
    () => Object.values(b) (4) [undefined, undefined, undefined, "k3"]
test [,,,'k3']
    for() =>                     count: 4
    for in() =>                  count: 1
    for of() =>                  count: 4
    _arr.forEach() =>            count: 1
    _arr.map() =>                count: 1
    _arr.filter(_k => true)() => count: 1 перед фильтрацией [ empty, empty, empty, k3 ] после [ k3 ]
test [undefined,undefined,undefined,'k3']
    for() =>                     count: 4
    for in() =>                  count: 4
    for of() =>                  count: 4
    _arr.forEach() =>            count: 4
    _arr.map() =>                count: 4
    _arr.filter(_k => true)() => count: 4 перед фильтрацией [ undefined, undefined, undefined, k3 ] после [ undefined, undefined, undefined, k3 ]
```

исходники:

```js
group(function count() {
    let a = [,,,'k3']
    let b = [undefined,undefined,undefined,'k3']

    log(() => Object.keys(a))
    log(() => Object.values(a))

    log(() => Object.keys(b))
    log(() => Object.values(b))

    let o = {
        'for'(_arr) {
        let count = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < _arr.length; i++) {
            count++
        }
        return(`count: ${count}`)
        },
        'for in'(_arr) {
        let count = 0
        for (var i in _arr) {
            count++
        }
        return(`count: ${count}`)
        },
        'for of'(_arr) {
        let count = 0
        for (var i of _arr) {
            count++
        }
        return(`count: ${count}`)
        },
        '_arr.forEach'(_arr) {
        let count = 0
        _arr.forEach(_k => {
            count++
        });
        return(`count: ${count}`)
        },
        '_arr.map'(_arr) {
        let count = 0
        _arr.map(_k => {
            count++
        });
        return(`count: ${count}`)
        },
        '_arr.filter(_k => true)'(_arr) {
        let count = 0
        let res = []
        let before = `перед фильтрацией ${arrToString(_arr)}`
        let after = null
        _arr = _arr.filter(_k => {
            count++
            return true
        });
        res.push(`count: ${count}`)
        after = `после ${arrToString(_arr)}`
        res.push(before)
        res.push(after)
        return res.join(' ')
        },
        // 'for'(){},
    }
    let o2 = {
        "test [,,,'k3']"() {
        Object.values(o).forEach(_f => {
            log(`${_f.name}() => ${_f(a)}`)
        })
        },
        "test [undefined,undefined,undefined,'k3']"() {
        Object.values(o).forEach(_f => {
            log(`${_f.name}() => ${_f(b)}`)
        })
        },
    }
    Object.values(o2).forEach(group)

})
```

```html
<script>let group = a => {let b = console;b.group('qwa ' + a.name || ((a.prototype) ? a : 'anonym'));try { a() } catch (d) { b.log(d) }b.groupEnd()};let log = a => a instanceof Function ? console.log(a,a()) : console.log(a); function arrToString(a) { if ('[object Array]' !== Object.prototype.toString.call(a)) throw new TypeError('_arr !==  "[object Array]"'); let b = [],c = null; for (var d = 0; d < a.length; d++)c = a[d],d in a ? void 0 === c ? b.push('undefined') : b.push('' + c) : b.push('empty'); return `[ ${b.join(', ')} ]` }</script>
```

### 2.3 замеры времени

дано:

две матрицы (двумерный массив) `matrixA` и `matrixB`
ширина = 1366
высота 768
это характеристики моего монитора
каждая из них в самом конце (нижний правый угол монитора) содержит единичку
`matrixA` состоит из `empty`
`matrixB` состоит из `undefined`

задача:

запустить таймер, найти единичку (в самом конце), и остановить таймер.

ответ в миллисекундах:

```
() => test_for_in(matrixA) 2
() => test_for_in(matrixB) 206

() => test_for_of(matrixA) 122
() => test_for_of(matrixB) 130

() => test_for(matrixA) 122
() => test_for(matrixB) 115
```

решение:

```js
group(function matrix() {

    let width = 1366
    let height = 768
    let a = _n => Array(_n)
    let matrixA = Array.from({ length: height },() => a(width))
    setLast(matrixA)
    let b = _n => Array.from({ length: _n },() => undefined)
    let matrixB = Array.from({ length: height },() => b(width))
    setLast(matrixB)

    log(() => test_for_in(matrixA))
    log(() => test_for_in(matrixB))

    log(() => test_for_of(matrixA))
    log(() => test_for_of(matrixB))

    log(() => test_for(matrixA))
    log(() => test_for(matrixB))

    function setLast(matrix) {
        let lastArr = matrix[matrix.length - 1]
        lastArr[lastArr.length - 1] = 1
    }

    function test_for_in(matrix) {
        let start = null
        let end = null
        start = Date.now()
        for (var i in matrix) {
            for (var j in matrix[i]) {
                if (matrix[i][j] = 1) {
                    end = Date.now() - start
                }
            }
        }
        return end
    }
    function test_for_of(matrix) {
        let start = null
        let end = null
        start = Date.now()
        for (var arr of matrix) {
            for (var val of arr) {
                if (val = 1) {
                    end = Date.now() - start
                }
            }
        }
        return end
    }
    function test_for(matrix) {
        let start = null
        let end = null
        start = Date.now()
        for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] = 1) {
                    end = Date.now() - start
                }
            }
        }
        return end
    }
})
```

```html
<script>let group=a=>{let b=console;b.group(a.name||((a.prototype)?a:'anonym'));try { a() } catch (d) { b.log(d) }b.groupEnd()};let log = a => a instanceof Function ? console.log(a,a()) : console.log(a); function arrToString(a) { if ('[object Array]' !== Object.prototype.toString.call(a)) throw new TypeError('_arr !==  "[object Array]"'); let b = [],c = null; for (var d = 0; d < a.length; d++)c = a[d],d in a ? void 0 === c ? b.push('undefined') : b.push('' + c) : b.push('empty'); return `[ ${b.join(', ')} ]` }</script>
```

### 2.4 персонально для @yar85

**объект** и **массив** помещённые в массив являются ссылками, операция `delete` и присвоения `undefined` удаляет только ссылку из массива. такие объекты удаляются из памяти в случае, а об этом читаем тут [learn.javascript.ru/memory-management](https://learn.javascript.ru/memory-management)

```js
{
    let o = {
        'ссылка на объект'() {
            let arr = []
            let o = { name: 'O' }
            arr.push(o)
            // delete arr[0]      // log(()=>f) // () => o {name: "O"}
            // arr[0] = undefined // log(()=>f) // () => o {name: "O"}
            log(() => o)
        },
        'ссылка на массив'() {
            let arr = []
            let arr2 = ['arr2']
            arr.push(arr2)
            // delete arr[0]      // log(()=>f) // () => arr2 ["arr2"]
            // arr[0] = undefined // log(()=>f) // () => arr2 ["arr2"]
            log(() => arr2)
        },

    }
    Object.values(o).forEach(group)
}
```

### 2.5 Оператор расширения (spread)

```js
group(function spread() {
    let arr = [,,,'C']
    let arr2 = [...arr]
    log(() => arr2) // (4) [undefined, undefined, undefined, "C"]
})
```

```html
<script>let group = a => {let b = console;b.group('qwa ' + a.name || ((a.prototype) ? a : 'anonym'));try { a() } catch (d) { b.log(d) }b.groupEnd()};let log = a => a instanceof Function ? console.log(a,a()) : console.log(a); function arrToString(a) { if ('[object Array]' !== Object.prototype.toString.call(a)) throw new TypeError('_arr !==  "[object Array]"'); let b = [],c = null; for (var d = 0; d < a.length; d++)c = a[d],d in a ? void 0 === c ? b.push('undefined') : b.push('' + c) : b.push('empty'); return `[ ${b.join(', ')} ]` }</script>
```

Comment: Может стоит сначала подготовить вопросом с ответом и только потом публиковать?

Comment: может, но мне, сейчас нужна ссылка на этот вопрос

Comment: Можно создать ответ для получения ссылки и сразу же его удалить. В дальнейшем, как появится содержимое, восстановить. Ответы «на вырост» попадают в очереди проверок, привлекают минуса и тревоги.

Comment: _оператор delete сразу освобождает память_ - зависит от реализации

Comment: @Grundy, вы знаете случай когда очистка с помощью `delete` сработает так же как `undefined` ?

Comment: какая связь между _оператор delete сразу освобождает память_ и _очистка с помощью delete сработает так же как undefined_? Удаление биндинга ничего не имеет общего с освобождением памяти, как собственно и присваивание значения, даже значения _undefined_

Answer (score 8):

> Ещё реже встречаются люди, которые знают о существовании *метода* delete

`delete` - **оператор**, а не метод!

> В чём различия при удалении элемента массива методами undefined и delete

Присвоение `undefined` и оператор `delete` не удаляют элемент массива. Они "удаляют"/устанавливают значение, содержащееся в массиве. Сам элемент массива, после такого "удаления" остается - он становится *не определенным*, но позволяет выполнять операции с ним (смысл термина `элемент` !== смыслу термина `содержимое элемента`. Хотя, безусловно, ==).
А различие в том, что присвоение `undefined` - это **присвоение** значения, со всеми вытекающими последствиями... тогда как `delete`, именно удаляет содержимое элемента.

---

Для удаления элементов массива, в JavaScript существует [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Прямое назначение метода как раз в этом (и в добавлении элементов). А `delete` - предназначен для удаления свойств объектов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75688/discussion-on-answer-by-yar85---o---undefined).

Answer (score 3):

Главное различие - что оператор *delete* удаляет элемент массива. Хоть при этом длинна массива не изменится и адресовать удалённый элемент вы по прежнему сможете. Но оператор *in* не обнаружит элемент удалённый таким способом:

```
let arr = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
arr[2] = undefined
console.log(2 in arr)  // ===> true
delete arr[3]
console.log(3 in arr) // ===> false
```

Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Unary)