# Дан массив [1, 'abc', [], [a], {}, {name: "ololo"}, null, 0]

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты, методы

Напишите функцию которая вернет новый массив без пустых значений
(пустой массив и пустой объект - тоже расцениваются как пустые значения).
Не могу понять как убрать пустой массив и пустой объект.

```js
let arr = [1, 'abc', [], ['a'], {}, {name: "ololo"}, null, 0];
arr = arr.filter(function(e){ return e === 0 || e });
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Как отфильтровать массив?

Использовать метод `filter`.

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].filter(q => q > 5)
```

Но если массив состоит не только из цифр.
Но если нужно сделать много проверок на различные условия.

То в этом случае - задача сильно усложнится и станет всё запутанным.

Но это на первый взгляд, задачу можно сильно упростить, если завести массив проверочных функций. А если их объявление делать внутри объекта - так вообще всё будет: и просто, и код аккуратен и структурирован.

Смотри мой пример ниже.

### Как проверить каждый элемент массива на большое количество условий?

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=22&ssc=11&pln=22&pc=10#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApjAvDAjugfDA8gEYBWywUAdIgE4hR1LIX0DKU1AlmAOYXACGAG0EAKTAEoAsACgZoSLA4QAXDAAkSgDJLYGAN4yYRmG049V2NHgDkAbRAkysU124Bda+jQYEKMeIAaQ2MiUnILXBg7BzDYUKcPLx9GfyDpYxgAQWpqfngIqyj7R3IsnLzE72S-CTSMgDkAVwBbQmRqApti2Jgm1vbK7zgU2pkAXxkZX1QNCHQYMVV+MHhxSMIQEEFkZcnpafUtHXm9GFsAa1VoM3dVWZgJ6XloGAB9JTujl-1gowAtdogTowAAMSSwdWMTWEwLAjWE4MwkKMAFUwAATZAAMy4yHRwMaGOxuPRiORMABtBc5gWmCu7Fca0KSgo1O4-hgADJOaDERRtjwoAALcmUkDaaCqRYwZbwWxuJl4FnZXLwDnc3lVLD85CCkW-CmA+r8Zp4iVQKV0mB6MaKmAs+LkdU8sFax2Uc7IeAQfw6vVpR5TRjqd4Qc3zWbymQAemjMAAAlAIABaDjcMAgajIOTgF6h813fPHDDuigANyEjWQPtDUlkT1zsBxgig7Xm0tldoAhEXoBQICBTSIsZEsf46zJtrB+Dl5rYAIwBKL8QjAaxL+Ub6z8axuJc2-cwMAm5CqABEW0vZ4eS7hwiXILcAG4ZDPqPM3xRm63qMOOC32gnBtIC2JhBBAdk33EJ8gA)

---

тут запустить:

```js
const type = q => Object.prototype.toString.call(q);

const is = {
    String: q => '[object String]' === type(q),
    Object: q => '[object Object]' === type(q),
    Array: q => '[object Array]' === type(q),
    Number: q => '[object Number]' === type(q),
};

const _is = {
    Zero: q => 0 === q,
    Null: q => null === q,
    Undefined: q => undefined === q,
    ZeroString: q => is.String(q) && 0 === q.length,
    ZeroList: q => is.Array(q) && 0 === q.length,
    ZeroNamedList: q => is.Object(q) && 0 === Object.keys(q).length,
};


const _isList = Object.values(_is);
const filter = q => !_isList.some(f => f(q));


let arr = [1, 'abc', [], ['a'], {}, { name: "ololo" }, null, 0];
arr = arr.filter(filter);

console.log(arr);
```

---

тут доки:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag

---

небольшое замечание к коду:

```js
const obj = {
    q: undefined
}

console.log(
    Object.keys(obj)
) // ["q"]
```

Ах, ДА! Не забываем что ещё есть такая штука как `empty` - [Есть ли бóльшая пустота чем undefined?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/810426/232932)

Answer (score 0):

Держи )

```
let arr = [1, 'abc', [], ['a'], {}, {name: "ololo"}, null, 0];
arr = arr.filter(function(e){ return e != '' && e != null && (typeof(e) == 'object' ? Object.keys(e).length != 0 : e)});
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: В конце у тебя `a`

Comment: Спасибо, что то не выспался видать )

Comment: Почитай про es6, `arrow funcs` и `return` можно убрать с фигурками

Comment: Читал, знаю. Но все равно спасибо )

Comment: Асуждаю тогда))

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = [1, 'abc', [], ['a'], {}, {name: "ololo"}, null, 0];

arr = arr.filter((e)=>(e === 0 || e && (e !== '') && (typeof(e) === 'object' ? Object.keys(e).length !== 0 : e)));

console.log(arr);
```