# Javascript: Почему Array.some() не находит пустые ячейки массива?

Tags: javascript

**Спасибо @Eugene-X за то, что ткнул носом, ответ есть в документации на MDN: для пустых массивов some() всегда возвращает false.**

**UPD. почему после добавления значений в некоторые ячейки, some() всё равно возвращает false, как для пустого массива. Очевидно, итерация идёт только по "не-пустым" значениям, для которых приведенное условие не выполняется:**

```
arr = new Array(10);
arr[2] = "значение";
arr[6] = 400;
arr.some( elem => !elem) // возвращает false
```

---

Есть массив, созданный таким образом:

```
arr = new Array(10);
```

Соответственно, он содержит 10 пустых ячеек. При обращении к любой из них javascript возвращает undefined, и проверка на строгое равенство undefined возвращает true:

```
arr[2] // возвращает undefined
arr[5] === undefined // возвращает true
```

Почему тогда следующий код возвращает false? (проверено в firefox и chrome)

```
arr.some( elem => !elem) // возвращает false
```

Пробовал вместо "elem => !elem" ставить "elem => elem == undefined" (строго и нестрого), использовать Boolean(), а также объявлять функцию выше в коде и передавать её в .some() по имени, но это ожидаемо не повлияло на результат.

Я таким способом добавлять значения только в еще пустые ячейки (в некоторые произвольные ранее уже добавлены значения). понимаю, что такого эффекта можно добиться без использования .some(), но хотел бы понять причину такого поведения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Есть ли бóльшая пустота чем undefined?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810426/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%c3%b3%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-undefined)

Comment: Потому что some подразумевает итерацию, а итерировать пустые массивы нельзя!  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Даже на MozDev это выделено отдельно! `Обратите внимание: метод возвращает false при любом условии для пустого массива.`

Answer (score 2):

Все методы массива, такие как [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) и т.д. проходят только по **существующим** индексам массива, таким, для которых

```
arr.hasOwnProperty(key) === true
```

У дырок в массиве нет соответствующих ключей, поэтому они и пропускаются. Также стандартным поведением является возврат `undefined` при попытке обратиться к отсутствующему ключу.